# Total Distance Travelled by Particle

Tags: calculus

The velocity of a particle moving along the $x$-axis is $$v(t) = \cos(2t)$$ with $t$ measured in minutes and $v(t)$ measured in feet per minute. To the nearest foot find the total distance travelled by the particle from $t = 0$ to $t = π$ minutes.

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far? What are your thoughts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: 2 ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Right so what I thought was to graph the integral of the function, marking where the line intersected the x-intercept and create a t\ v(t) chart from that and plug the t values into the original equation but it's giving me long decimals. Not sure what to do next or what to change. @RoryDaulton

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language appropriate to assigning homework.  It can make one wonder if the poster copied a question without understanding it. If you don't understand a homework question you could ask about that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note that $v$ changes sign a few times. You need to be careful how you calculate the total distance travelled.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^\pi v(t)\,dt = \int_0^\pi \cos (2t) \, dt = 0,
$$
and that means the distance from the starting point to the end point is $0$.  So in *one* sense that is the total distance traveled.  However, it didn't remain in one place.  If you integrate the *speed*, which is the absolute value of the velocity, with respect to time, you get the total length of the path the particle followed.  Thus you have
$$
\int_0^\pi |\cos(2t)|\,dt = \int_\cdots^\cdots \cos(2t)\,dt + \int_\cdots^\cdots (-\cos(2t))\,dt.
$$
You have to figure out what the bounds of integration are, i.e. for which values of $t$ is $\cos(2t)\ge0$ and for which is $\cos(2t)<0$.